# How can I generate a safe class name from a file name?

Tags: c#, razor, compilation, code-generation

I'm trying to produce some dynamically compiled code with the Razor engine, and I want to name the generated classes according to their source file names to help understand where a piece of generated code comes from.

For example, I would expect the file C:\source\Foo.cs to be compile with the name `Foo`.

Given that I have the path to the source file being compiled, is there a way to generate a valid C# identifier based on the file name?

Comment: It seems odd to me that you wouldn't create the class names first and then generate the file names from those.

Comment: That's not how the Razor template engine works; it generates a class from a file of markup.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the C# spec, the following rules must be adhered to when creating identifiers:

- An identifier must start with a letter or an underscore
- After the first character, it may contain numbers, letters, connectors, etc
- If the identifier is a keyword, it must be prepended with “@”

This helper will satisfy those conditions:

```
private static string GenerateClassName(string value)
{
    string className = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(value);
    bool isValid = Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider.CreateProvider("C#").IsValidIdentifier(className);

    if (!isValid)
    { 
        // File name contains invalid chars, remove them
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"[^\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lo}\p{Nd}\p{Nl}\p{Mn}\p{Mc}\p{Cf}\p{Pc}\p{Lm}]");
        className = regex.Replace(className, "");

        // Class name doesn't begin with a letter, insert an underscore
        if (!char.IsLetter(className, 0))
        {
            className = className.Insert(0, "_");
        }
    }

    return className.Replace(" ", string.Empty);
}
```

It first converts the file name to camel case (personal preference), it then uses [IsValidIdentifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.codedomprovider.isvalididentifier(v=vs.110).aspx) to determine if the file name is already valid for a class name.

If not, it will remove all invalid characters based on the [unicode character classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx). It then checks whether the file name starts with a letter, if it does, it prepends an `_` to fix it.

Finally, I remove all whitespace (even though it would still be a valid identifier with it).

Comment: I will use a version of this which replaces whitespace and hyphens with underscores. The key section is certainly the negated regex; I had no idea you could reference unicode character sets!

Comment: `I had no idea you could reference unicode character sets` - you can also use named character blocks e.g. `\p{IsGreek}+` or `\p{IsHebrew}+` which I thought was pretty cool

Comment: @DGibbs Should the Regex replace result be assigned to `ret` or back to `classname`? I suspect the latter.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to extract the File-Name, for example with:

```
Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension
```

Then you have to follow all rules, a c#-class name has.
For example

1. Starting with a letter or _
2. i would remove all other characters than _ AND a-z AND 0-9

This should be all!

Answer (score 0):

did you look at the codedom  - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404245(v=vs.110).aspx ?

Answer (score 0):

Take the path, replace the invalid characters like `\` with let's say `_` and you're done.

If you prefer shorter names, you could take the path, transform it to lowercase and take a hash value.

Some code sample:

```
var className = pathIncludingFilename.ToLowerSinceCasingIsNotRelevant().SomeHashFunctionLikeSha1OrPartOfIt() + filename.RemoveInvalidCharactersLikeWhitespace();
```

The result may look like this:

123a3b6b22foo

The hash should ensure unique names, the filename makes it easier to correlate.